# Random password generator returning undefined along with generated password (javascript)

Tags: javascript, function, passwords, undefined

**EXAMPLE OUTPUT**

```
undefined@pz#$n%s!@$@p!y
```

- `userInput` prompts the user for the characters they would like in their password.
- `generatePassword` takes the user condition and adds it to an array which then picks from random strings in the array.

I'm having a difficult time figuring out why `undefined  gets returned along with the password.

```js
var generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");
var upperCaseLetters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];
var lowerCaseLetters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
var numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var symbols = ["!", "@", "#", "$", "%"];
var pw = [];
// Write password to the #password input
function writePassword() {
  var pwCriteria = getUserInput();
  //console.log(pwCriteria);
  var password = generatePassword(pwCriteria);
  //console.log(password);
  var passwordText = document.querySelector("#password");

  //Math.random();

  passwordText.value = password;

}

function generatePassword(criteria) {
  var pw = [];
  if (criteria.lowerCase) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= criteria.length; i++) {
      var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * lowerCaseLetters.length);
      var randomChar = lowerCaseLetters[randomIndex];
      console.log(randomIndex);
      console.log(randomChar);
      pw = pw + randomChar;
    }
  }

  if (criteria.upperCase) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= criteria.length; i++) {
      var randomIndex2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * upperCaseLetters.length);
      var randomChar = upperCaseLetters[randomIndex2];
      pw = pw + randomChar;
    }
  }
  if (criteria.specialChar) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= criteria.length; i++) {
      var randomIndex3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * symbols.length);
      var randomChar = symbols[randomIndex3];
      pw = pw + randomChar;
    }
  }

  if (criteria.num) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= criteria.length; i++) {
      var randomIndex5 = Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length);
      var randomChar = numbers[randomIndex5];
      pw = pw + randomChar;
    }
  }

  if (criteria.lowerCase === false && criteria.upperCase === false && criteria.specialChar === false && criteria.num === false) {
    alert("You must choose at least one character type to put in your password.")
  }

  for (var i = 0; i <= criteria.length - 1; i++) {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * pw.length);
    var str = pw[random];
    var newPw = newPw + str;
  }

  return newPw;

}

function getUserInput() {
  var length = parseInt(prompt("How many characters would you like your password to be? (Between 8 and 128)"));
  if (length >= 8 && length <= 128) {} else {
    alert("The password has to be between 8 and 128 characters");
    return getUserInput();
  }
  var lowerCase = confirm("Would you like lowercase characters in your password?");
  var upperCase = confirm("Would you like uppercase characters in your password?");
  var specialChar = confirm("Would you like special characters in your password?");
  var num = confirm("Would you like your password to have numbers in it?");
  return {
    length: parseInt(length),
    lowerCase,
    upperCase,
    specialChar,
    num,
  }
}
// Add event listener to generate button
generateBtn.addEventListener("click", writePassword);
```

```html
<input id="password"/><button class="button" id="generate">Generate</button>
```

Comment: `var newPw = newPw + str;` Initialize `newPw` first and don't use `var` there.

Comment: also, why was pw initialized with an empty array if you are going to be adding random chars to it

Comment: Voting to clse as _Not reproducible or was caused by a typo.
While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Comment: Push to `pw` and scramble the array before showing

Comment: Also `someBoolean === false` can always be written `!someBoolean`

Comment: @mplungjan: Not necessarily.

Comment: @JavaScript If it is true or false you NEVER need to test === true or === false

Comment: @mplungjan: That part is true. Still `someBoolean === false` is not the same as `!someBoolean` and depending on the requirements, could be wrong. Yet, I am pretty sure you are aware of that.

Comment: Come on. After you do x=false; no need to test x===false

Comment: I am not the one that made a pretty broad general statement,

Answer (score 0):

Push to pw or better: map

I just had to rewrite this

I tried to be as DRY as possible while retaining readability

I did not touch the input creation

```js
const generateBtn = document.getElementById("generate"); // IDs are unique, no need for querySelector
const passwordText = document.getElementById("password");
const getRnd = arr => arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]
const letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
const upperCaseLetters = [...letters]; // spread to array
const lowerCaseLetters = [...letters.toLowerCase()];
const numbers = [..."0123456789"];
const symbols = [..."!@#$%"];
let pw = [];

generateBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const pwCriteria = getUserInput();
  passwordText.value = generatePassword(pwCriteria);
});


function generatePassword(criteria) {
  if (!criteria.lowerCase &&
    !criteria.upperCase &&
    !criteria.specialChar &&
    !criteria.num) {
    alert("You must choose at least one character type to put in your password.")
    return;
  }
  const lengthArr = [...Array(criteria.length).keys()]; // create an array just for the map's sake

  if (criteria.lowerCase) pw = pw.concat(lengthArr.map(num => getRnd(lowerCaseLetters)));
  if (criteria.upperCase) pw = pw.concat(lengthArr.map(num => getRnd(upperCaseLetters)));
  if (criteria.specialChar) pw = pw.concat(lengthArr.map(num => getRnd(symbols)));
  if (criteria.num) pw = pw.concat(lengthArr.map(num => getRnd(numbers)));
  console.log(pw)
  return pw // shuffle from https://stackoverflow.com/a/46545530/295783
    .map((a) => ({
      sort: Math.random(),
      value: a
    }))
    .sort((a, b) => a.sort - b.sort)
    .map((a) => a.value)
    .join("")
    .slice(0,criteria.length);

}

function getUserInput() {
  var length = parseInt(prompt("How many characters would you like your password to be? (Between 8 and 128)"));
  if (length >= 8 && length <= 128) {} else {
    alert("The password has to be between 8 and 128 characters");
    return getUserInput();
  }
  var lowerCase = confirm("Would you like lowercase characters in your password?");
  var upperCase = confirm("Would you like uppercase characters in your password?");
  var specialChar = confirm("Would you like special characters in your password?");
  var num = confirm("Would you like your password to have numbers in it?");
  return {
    length: parseInt(length),
    lowerCase,
    upperCase,
    specialChar,
    num,
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="password" /><button class="button" id="generate">Generate</button>
```